# How do I solve void function printing null?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write something in C, And I'm having this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[2048];

void read(char input){
    printf("%s", input);
}

int main(){
    fputs("test> ", stdout);
    
    fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
    
    read(input[2048]);
}
```

Above is the source code, Whenever the user inputs something, It goes to a void function then tries to print out the input, But it's printing out "(null)", I tried to make the void function like:

```
void read(char *input){
    printf("%s", input);
}
```

But it still didn't solve the problem, Can someone please solve this problem for me, It's really important to me, And I would appreciate the help so much, Thanks!

Comment: input[2048] means the 2049th letter of the input

Comment: Please describe what do you want to happen when you `read(input[2048]);` is executed. Also explain why a function that *prints* should be called `read`.

Comment: @user253751 ...which does not exist..

Comment: "How do I solve void function printing null?" --> Save time and enable all compiler warnings. **This** is the most important thing to learn from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You passed a single `char` to `read`, not the string. And you passed a character from *outside* the declared array, which invokes undefined behavior (you're "lucky" there happened to be a `0` in that byte, so the program just printed `(null)` instead of segfaulting as it tried to read a string from memory addresses beginning between `0x1` and `0xFF`).

You need to accept a pointer to (`const`) `char` and pass it properly from the caller:

```
void read(const char *input){  // Receive pointer to string, not single character
    printf("%s", input);
}

int main(){
    fputs("test> ", stdout);
    
    fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
    
    read(input);  // Passes pointer to *first* element, not value of 2048th (which is out of bounds)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the help, I just learned C yesterday so yeah explains why I'm dumb.